# how to use google map v3 in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

how to use google map v3 in CakePHP.

Comment: Can you be a little more verbal about your problem?

Comment: i am new in cakePHP so i didn't know how to use Google maps i have to do geocoding

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP doesn't have any built-in support for Google Maps v3.

So you could either roll your own solution or you could use Google Maps API V3 Helper put together by Marc Fernandez Girones: [Google Maps API V3 Helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/marcferna/2010/05/27/google_maps_api_v3_helper_3).

I've never tried this helper myself so I can't recommend it one way or the other. But it might at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for recommending Marc's helper. Easy to use and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

my version:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/
at least for the maps stuff

for geocoding you should use a behavior

both can easily be found via google search (cakephp geocoding)

Answer (score 0):

I made that helper and it supports geocoding. Give it a try, it's pretty simple and easy to use. Let me know if you have any questions.

> you could use Google Maps API V3 Helper put together by Marc Fernandez Girones: [Google Maps API V3 Helper](https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper)

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Above link is broken, this one works; http://bakery.cakephp.org/%20%20%20articles/view/4caea0e7-4878-42e2-9c72-400f82f0cb67